# Finding the Expected Value for a joint discrete/continuous system

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know the basics of probability (e.g. the expected value of a discrete *or* continuous random variable) but I'm not sure how you compute the expected value for a more complicated system with joint-behavior.

For example, what would be the **expected value** for the following "game"?

Roll a 6 sided die:

- If you roll a $1$ or $2$, then flip a coin. Heads gives you the value you rolled; tails gives you $0$.
- If you roll a $3$ thru $6$, do the following: **(a)** If you rolled an even number, return a random real number between $0$ and the value you rolled. **(b)** If you rolled a odd number, return a random integer between $0$ and the value you rolled.

I am of course interested in the full, generalized explanation, but I thought it might be learnt best by applying it to a specific kind of problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nice thing about expected values is that they are *linear*, meaning that if you have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$, and two constants, $a$ and $b$, you can write $E[aX+bY] = aE[X] + bE[Y]$. It doesn't even matter that $X$ only results in certain discrete values and Y gives continuous values, because you can pull a little sleight of hand to treat them the same (there's essentially a continuous distribution that's equivalent to $X$ that gives you the same results if you look at its behaviour over intervals of the form $[n, n+1)$ or the like).

And, using the typical definition of expectation, we can say that the expected value of your process is equal to the expected value of each individual die outcome, weighted by the probability of each outcome (which is always $\frac{1}{6}$). So, assuming that when you say "random [real number|integer]" you're talking uniform distributions then we get something like this:

1. On a roll of [1|2], you get the result of [1|2] with chance 0.5 and 0 otherwise, giving expected value [0.5|1].
2. On a roll of [3|5], you get an integer selected uniformly from 0 to [3|5], so the expected value is [3|5]/2 = [1.5|2.5].
3. On a roll of [4|6], you get a real number selected uniformly from 0 to [4|6], so the expected value is [4|6]/2 = [2|3].

So the overall expected value is $\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2} + 1 + \frac{3}{2} + 2 + \frac{5}{2} + 3 \right) = \frac{1}{12}\left(1 + 2 + \ldots + 6\right) = \frac{21}{12} = \frac{7}{4} = 2.75$.

It certainly helps that in this case all individual die rolls result in a process whose expected value is half of the roll.

Comment: Thank you! This is quite helpful.

Comment: Linearity of Expectation is nice, but *pedantically*, this actually employs the Tower Property (aka *Law of Iterated Expectation*).  Let $X$ be the return and $Y$ be the result of the die.  Then:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)~=~&\mathsf E(\mathsf E(X\mid Y)) &~=~& \mathsf E(Y/2) \\[1ex] =~& \sum_{y=1}^6 \mathsf P(Y=y)~\mathsf E(X\mid Y=y) \\[1ex] =~& \tfrac 16(\tfrac 12+1+\tfrac 32+2+\tfrac 52+3) &~=~& \tfrac 74\end{align}$$